# Integral for $\dfrac{x^2}{e^x-1}$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

I am working on a physics research problem, and one of the integrals I am running into is an integral related to the Planck distribution, except for the x is to the power 2, not 3. I need help integrating the following expression:

$$\int \frac{x^2}{e^x-1} \, dx $$

A closed form solution to this would be nice, but if not I would like to integrate this from $x=x_0$ to $x=\infty$.
If a closed form solution is not possible, any expression would be nice.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+x%5E2+%2F+(e%5Ex+-+1)) answers in terms of log integrals.

Comment: I tried using it and it is giving answers in terms of polylogarithm functions. Is that the only way it can be expressed?

Comment: There are plenty of other ways to write it, I suppose. One possibility is to write the integrand as $$x^2 e^{-x} \left(\frac{1}{1 - e^{-x}}\right)$$ and expand as a geometric series.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the geometric sequence to integrate it. Use the well known identity$$\frac 1{t-1}=\sum\limits_{n\geq1}\frac 1{t^n}$$which converges for $|t|>1$ and replace the fraction with the infinite sum to get$$\begin{align*}\int\limits_{x_0}^{\infty} dx\,\frac {x^2}{e^x-1} & =\int\limits_{x_0}^{\infty} dx\,x^2\sum\limits_{n\geq1}e^{-nx}\\ & =\sum\limits_{n\geq1}\int\limits_{x_0}^{\infty} dx\, x^2 e^{-nx}\\ & =\sum\limits_{n\geq1}\frac 1{n^3}\int\limits_{nx_0}^{\infty}dx\, x^2e^{-x}\end{align*}$$From here, you can use the definition of the [incomplete gamma function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function)$$\Gamma(s,x)=\int\limits_x^{\infty}dt\, t^{s-1}e^{-t}$$To get$$\int\limits_{x_0}^{\infty}dx\,\frac {x^2}{e^x-1}=\zeta(3)\Gamma(3,nx_0)$$

However, if you are integrating specifically from zero to infinity, then you can get this well known result$$\int\limits_0^{\infty}dx\,\frac {x^{s-1}}{e^x-1}=\zeta(s)\Gamma(s)$$